# Could my deuterostome-like species exist?

Tags: science-fiction, evolution, immortality, sapience

I am writing a science-fantasy story that is set in a pseudo-post-apocalyptic Earth ten million years in the future, and it is about a strange creature that looks vaguely a deuterostome called Céleste Bizarre. They belong (Céleste Bizarre is non-binary like me) to a species called bizarre (*Bizarrus sapiens*). Basic characteristics of my bizarres include:

1. They are solitary but social like orangutans;
2. They can drink saltwater without getting dehydrated like manatees;
3. They are hermaphroditic like gastropods;
4. Their average size is 1.47 meters and 70 kilograms (or 4 feet 10 inches and 154 pounds) (the same height as Danny DeVito);
5. They age in a similar way as immortal jellyfish (except that they complete their lifecycle in 60 years);
6. They have an improved sense of hearing, but they do have a relatively poor sense of smell, and they have a good color vision: they have four cones, a cone sensible to ultraviolet, a cone sensible to blue, a cone sensible to green, and a cone sensible to red, but they are myopic (or nearsighted if you want) ;
7. They are bipedal;
8. They have a seal-like blubber;
9. They have the same skin color variation than humans;
10. They have a chimpanzee-like fur with the same color variation than humans;
11. They have the same variation eye color variation than humans, and many have epicanthic folds;
12. They are omnivorous like brown rats (for the meat-eating part, they are mostly scavengers but will occasionally act as ambush predators, more rarely as pursuit predators) (for the plant-eating part, they are mostly frugivores and granivores, but will occasionally act as both florivores and folivores);
13. They have gorilla-level strength;
14. They are as fast as grey wolves;
15. They have human-level intelligence.

Given these characteristics, what species could they have evolved from, and what evolutionary pressures would lead to them?

Magic exists in my world after both many nuclear explosions and global warming that has accelerated evolution.

Comment: Sure, why not? What's the actual question here? (Single specific question, with identifiable best answer, that's what we need.)

Comment: Could they exist and from what could my bizarres have evolved from?

Comment: Like I said - THE question.  Sorry to shout, but we deal with single question at a time.

Comment: THE question is could my bizarres exist?

Comment: Why would you think they couldn't? The issues you've presented us with here are just fine in science fiction - in your world. But you haven't told us about your world, the environment in which these creatures are supposed to have developed. Tell us about the specific worldbuilding issue that you need help with. We're not here to give validation so much as to help with problems, you've not given us a problem to solve.

Comment: Your edit doesn't help clarify the problem you need solving. What do you need from us?

Comment: Well, quite obviously the main evolutionary pressure was the need to satisfy the requirements of Dark Purple Mammal Twice MMCCCXLVII. (And what on earth does it mean to look like a deuterostome? Starfish, sea cucumbers, salps, crinoids, lampreys and hummingbirds are all deuterostomes: and I don't see how they look similar.)

Answer (score 2):

**They evolved from gastropods.**

You made it easy:  3:  They are hermaphroditic like gastropods

The reproductive machinery is far and away the trickiest thing of all the stuff you lay out.  Everything else like size, strength, cologne brand are just permutations of body plan.   Intelligence is second trickiest but gastropods are molluscs as are octopi and so octopoid intelligence is within reach for gastropods that smell like Danny DeVito.

Comment: I'm beginning to get the impression that your quality/comedy answers are veering more in the comedy direction.

Comment: Why would they smell like Danny DeVito? Who even _is_ Danny DeVito?

Comment: If you cant have fun with saltwater sipping hermaphroditic Danny DeVitos,  FUN WOULD BE DEAD!  But no.  Fun lives!

Comment: The thing is... they need to be able to drink salt water

Comment: Actually, they evolved from stem-gastropods, similar to the extant Monoplacophores. We need to avoid that pesky gastropodal torsion. +1.